# CMake executable runs slower than running in ROOT

Tags: makefile, cmake, gsl

I wrote a macro for ROOT with the following libraries:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include <vector>
#include <iomanip>
#include <time.h> 
#include <stdio.h>

#include <gsl/gsl_matrix.h>
#include <gsl/gsl_odeiv2.h>

//ROOT libraries
#include <TTree.h>
#include <TFile.h>
```

When running in ROOT with .x script.cpp, it works fine and takes 0.25 seconds to write a root file.

Then, I created an executable using CMake. For that, I created the next CMakeLists files:

This CMakeLists file is outside the directory where the .cpp file is

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.6)
project(CMAKE_TEST)


find_package(GSL)
find_package(ROOT REQUIRED COMPONENTS)


set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-g++ -O2 -Wall")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS ${ROOT_CXX_FLAGS})
add_subdirectory(script_sub)
```

This is the one that is inside (same location as the .cpp file)

```
include_directories(${CMAKE_TEST_SOURCE_DIR}/script_sub)
link_directories(${CMAKE_TEST_BINARY_DIR}/script_sub)


include(${ROOT_USE_FILE})

set(CORELIBS ${ROOT_LIBRARIES} ${GSL_LIBRARIES} m)

add_executable(script script.cpp)
target_link_libraries(script ${CORELIBS})
```

CMake creates the Makefile just fine, and then I can run `make` with no problems either. The issue is that when running the executable by `./script`, this writes the root file in 0.92 seconds, i.e., it is slower than running the code in ROOT. The results are correct, and I see no error message.
How is this possible?

Comment: You may compare command lines: one used when compile the executable with CMake, and one when compile the executable with ROOT. The first command line can be viewed with `make VERBOSE=1`.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. When running with .x script.cpp, there is no command line, just print what I say in my code. If I use make VERBOSE=1, it does show a lot of information messages, but no errors